# customizing shortcuts firefox webextention

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Does anybody know whether it's possible to add a keyboard shortcut to a Firefox webextention add-on where the modifier key is stored by the Storage api, and hence cannot be hard coded?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a content script to add the hotkey to every website that is visited, and you can add a content script to many pages, like the options page for google chrome, so if that page were open then the hotkey would not work.

storing it in storage api is not an issue.